# How to create a regex for the following scenario (HTML)?

Tags: python, html, regex

I have a few known formats in an HTML page, I need to parse the content of the tags

```
<TR>
    <TD align=center>Reissue of:</TD>
    <TD align=center> **VALUES_TO_FIND** </TD>
    <TD> </TD> 
</TR>
<TR>
    <TD align=center> </TD>
</TR>
```

basically I thought I can concatenate the HTML with a regular expression that will match anything inside the spot I'm looking for.

I know that the text before and after VALUES_TO_FIND will always be the same. how can I find it using RE? (I'm dealing with several cases and the format can repeat in several places in the page.

Comment: [You can't parse XHTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/159319)

Comment: In general you could look at `re.findall()`, but I don't think that reg exp will work in your case - there is no unique prefix/suffix in the provided data sample. How will you tell "Reissue of:" from " VALUES_TO_FIND " - both have the same prefix and suffix.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: '<TR><TD align=center>Reissue of:</TD><TD align=center>' + REGEX + '</TD><TD</TD> </TR><TR><TD align=center></TD></TR></TABLE><HR>'
I'm using regex because I have a format which gives me problems when using lxml\beautifulsoup)

Comment: You should not parse HTML with regex. It's not a reliable solution. 
This thread can tell you more about it. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags   @MartijnPieters I missed the Python tag, so changed my answer into comment

Comment: @Juhana: The OP has yet to run into the problem in the linked question; this is not a dupe of that post. It probably is a dupe of many other questions here on SO, though.

Comment: @YSY: Then ask questions about those problems, perhaps we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
import re

s="""
<TR>
    <TD align=center>Reissue of:</TD>
    <TD align=center> **VALUES_TO_FIND** </TD>
    <TD> </TD> 
</TR>
"""

p="""
<TR>
    <TD align=center>Reissue of:</TD>
    <TD align=center>(.*)</TD>
    <TD> </TD> 
</TR>
"""

m=re.search(p, s)
print m.group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use  regular expression to parse HTML (It's not a regular language).
There are many threads on the topic at stackoverflow.

I recommend you to use: BeautifulSoup, Pattern and similar modules.

Comment: These days, regular expressions aren't regular either: [The true power of regular expressions](http://nikic.github.com/2012/06/15/The-true-power-of-regular-expressions.html)

Comment: @NedBatchelder true, but that itself won't make them more readable that a CFG or a PEG. :-)

Comment: That's an awesome link, by the way. I believe the time has come to invent the term "irregular expression", or "iregex". :D

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I think you should generally use other things for HTML anyway, but "HTML is not regular" is a silly mantra.

Comment: Nay, what's silly here is calling these inventions "regular expressions". That's like inventing rational numbers and calling them "the new improved integers", then insisting 1.5 is an integer too.

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression will do:

```
re.findall(r'<TR>\s+<TD.+?</TD>\s+<TD align=center>(.*?)</TD>',html,re.DOTALL)
```

But I recommend using a parser.

Answer (score 0):

There are many better options for getting data out of HTML than regular expressions.  Try [Scrapy](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.14/intro/overview.html), for example.

Answer (score 0):

HTML isn't a regular language, using regular expression to work with it is difficult.

BeautifulSoup is a nice parser, here's an example how to use it:

```
from BeautifulSoup  import BeautifulSoup 

html = u'''
<TR>
    <TD align=center>Reissue of:</TD>
    <TD align=center> **VALUES_TO_FIND** </TD>
    <TD> </TD> 
</TR>
<TR>
    <TD align=center> </TD>
</TR>'''

bs = BeautifulSoup(html)

print [td.contents for td in bs.findAll('td')]
```

output:

```
[[u'Reissue of:'], [u' **VALUES_TO_FIND** '], [u' '], [u' ']]
```

You know what to do from here. :)

Install with `pip install BeautifulSoup`. Here are the docs:

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html